# Sum of 3x3 in 2D-Array

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program in java that read two 3 by 3 matrix and find out their sum and display result?

i tried this but i got Runtime error

```
Scanner r=new Scanner(System.in);
   int [][]array = null;
    int[][]array2 = null;
  int total=0;
  System.out.println("Enter matrix");
  for(int row=0;row<array.length;row++){
      for(int col=0;col<array[row].length;col++){
             array[row][col]=r.nextInt();

             array[row][col]=r.nextInt()
```

;

```
   System.out.print("   "+total +"  ");

      total=array[row][col]+array2[row][col];
        System.out.println("   ");
```

Comment: Just taking a wild shot in the dark here, but you should probably make it so that you don't get any runtime errors. Feel free to ask if you're having trouble resolving a particular error though.

Comment: you should calculate total before printing it

Comment: I think you need to get all the input and store it, before you start adding things up.  Otherwise your output will be all muddled in with your input.  So you'll have to traverse the arrays twice - once to collect the input and once to calculate and print the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first FOR-Loop demonstrates how to input values in the arrays. This code will require that the user inputs the values of both arrays simultaneously.

The second FOR-Loop demonstrates how to sum the values of each array. Later, both arrays are added together.

```
    //Since you know the the array will be 3x3,
    //declare it!
    int[][] array1 = new int[3][3];
    int[][] array2 = new int[3][3];

    int array1Total = 0;
    int array2Total = 0;
    int endResult;

    for (int x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < array1[x].length; y++) {

            array1[x][y] = r.nextInt();
            array2[x][y] = r.nextInt();

        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {

        for (int y = 0; y < array1[x].length; y++) {

            array1Total += array1[x][y];
            array2Total += array2[x][y];

        }
    }

    endResult = array1Total + array2Total;
```

Comment: I don't think this is what Reem meant by the sum of the two matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allocating any memory for the array references, they are referencing nothing(null)...
Try:

```
int[][] array = new int[3][3];
int[][] array2 = new int[3][3];
```

Also, you are missing a semi-colon in 9th line of your code.Also,in same line, I believe it should be array2 & not array.